# Returning a closure using vapply

Tags: r

If I have a function generator i.e.

```
prepend_text = function(text) {
  function(x) {
    paste(text, x)
  }
}
```

Is it possible to use vapply to return a vector of the resulting functions?  I do not know how to specify a return type of `closure` to vapply.

```
vapply(c('one', 'two', 'three'), FUN.VALUE=???, prepend_text)
```

Using any other value `character(1)` ect. yields

```
# Error in vapply(c('one', 'two', 'three'),  :
#   values must be type 'character',
#  but FUN(X[[1]]) result is type 'closure'
```

I think this may not be possible, and using `sapply` actually returns what I want, so this question is largely academic.

The output I am looking for has names for each function as well, so a simple `lapply` call will not work either.

expected output is equivalent to

```
c(one=prepend_text('one'), two=prepend_text('two'), three=prepend_text('three'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vapply` won't return functions, but `lapply` will. If you want to add names, you can set them on the input object:

```
x <- c('one', 'two', 'three')
names(x) <- x
lapply(x, prepend_text)
```

Comment: I did not know lapply preserves names on named vector inputs, thanks for the tip and answer winston!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use lapply in those situations.

Can you try this?

```
lapply(list('one', 'two', 'three'), prepend_text)
```

Good luck!

Comment: I should have specified I also wanted the name added to the output, I have modified the question slightly.